# Server HttpListner unable to read client certificate

Tags: httplistener

I have setup my server certificate, also I am able to add my client certificate on the HttpWebRequest call, but when the request gets to the server listener (now I am testing on my PC), it throws up the following error:

ClientCertificateError = 'context.Request.ClientCertificateError' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

The clientcertificate error displays

"base {System.SystemException} = {"Please call the GetClientCertificate()/BeginGetClientCertificate() method before calling this method."}"

How can i resolve this ?

Comment: paste your code here

Comment: if (context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    bool isClientValid = true;
    var clientCertificate = context.Request.GetClientCertificate(); // line that returns null
}

Comment: The concern really is why the Listener is unable to see the client certificate, then compiler recommending calling BeginGetClientCertificate() method ?

Comment: I tried calling the Async method BeginGetClientCertificate(null,null) this way, it says  "ELEMENT NOT FOUND". What exactly am i doing wrongly